# Difference between static & dynamic pages?

Tags: html, dynamic-pages, static-pages

I was doing some research on the types of web pages available and I came across these 2 types: static & dynamic. However, the sites which I read it from does not provide me with much information for me to understand what does these types of pages do and preferred for what kinds of websites/functions. Can anyone explain to me the functions of each of these 2 webpage types and tell me the difference/when to use them? Thanks! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between Static Website and Dynamic Website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49665855/whats-the-difference-between-static-website-and-dynamic-website)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Wikipedia:

> A static web page (sometimes called a flat page) is a web page that is delivered to the user exactly as stored, in contrast to dynamic web pages which are generated by a web application.

Here's a good comparison:
[Static Vs Dynamic websites - what's the difference?](http://www.edinteractive.co.uk/article/?id=4)