# What's the difference between Static Website and Dynamic Website?

Tags: web

As far as I know that static web sites are those which runs on client side only that means only html and javascript is fine for that. But dynamic web sites are those having executed in server sides too, that means using php, jsp or similar tools.

Why the names are so? - `Static` and `Dynamic`.

The main idea of my question is that we are still addressing a web page as static when `javascript` is used as it is a client-side language. But now-a-days, this concept is fading day by day, I guess. Because when `Ajax`, `node.js` or similar frameworks are used in a website, then my sense feels that those sites should have to be called dynamic sites as many dynamic contents can be produced using them. That's where lies my confusion.

So, is the concept of Static and Dynamic site is going to be obsolete in near future or use of javascript will not be considered in static sites any more? Or, may be I have some lackings in understanding the main view of calling the web sites as static and dynamic.

Answer (score 5):

A static site is one that is usually written in plain HTML and what is in the code of the page is what is displayed to the user.

A dynamic site is one that is written using a server-side scripting language such as PHP, ASP, JSP, or Coldfusion. In such a site the content is called in by the scripting language from other files or from a database depending on actions taken by the user.

Answer (score 4):

**Static website** - Contents don't change unless manually edited by someone.

(uses file extensions .html, .htm etc. for its pages)

**Dynamic website** - Contents update and change on their own without human intervention.

(uses file extensions .php, .jsp .asp etc.)

Answer (score 1):

In Web pages with html,css, visitors can’t do much other than passively look at the content on the pages. The communication’s one-way. That's static sites.

PHP allows you to manipulate web page content on the server just before a page is delivered to the client browser. It works like this: A PHP script runs on the server and can alter or generate HTML code at will. An HTML web page is still delivered to the browser, which doesn’t know or care that PHP is involved in tweaking the HTML on the server.

Comment: Head First PHP & MySQL by Michael Morrison, Lynn Beighley. You can refer to this book if you want to learn.